# Receiving payload request and displaying it on a webpage using spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

First of all I'm new to `Spring` and tried my best to get this working. So this is my question.

I have a spring MVC project which is supposed to receive a request payload (JSON request) and display the payload body on a webpage. Please see my project content and the controller class below

[image]

```
@Controller
public class CallbackPayloadController {

    public CallbackPayloadController() {
        System.out.println("In controller class!!!!");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/requestreceiver", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void receivePayload(@RequestBody String payload) {
        System.out.println("In the controller method....");
        System.out.println("Payload is : " + payload);
    }
}
```

Now if I do a POST to `http://localhost:8080/PayloadReceiver/requestreceiver/` using `POSTMAN` it says `HTTP STATUS 404`. My Json content that I am posting is

```
{
"key":"123"
}
```

My `web.xml` is as follows

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PayloadReceiver</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>requestreceiver</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>requestreceiver</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/requestreceiver.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/requestreceiver.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Second question is if I successfully receive the payload, how do I display the payload content on  a new webpage?

Comment: Post code as text, not images.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the `return` statement to your method like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/requestreceiver",consumes="...",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String receivePayload(...)
    ...
    return "requestreceiver";
```